# How to update badge counter in Parent tab page xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, badge

I have a App that uses tabbed pages, In the xaml of the  Parent tab page 
I populate all my other tab pages, I have a viewmodel that binds to the Parent tab page and viewmodels for each of the other Tab pages. I have a badge on one of the tabs that has a counter which shows how many messages there are.
I am having trouble updating the counter.

So I have a call to retrieve the amount of unread messages from the database which is populating into the counter on app load. When i Navigate to view the message it updates the database of that the message has been read , I then navigate back to the tabbed page with a popasync , I then pull to refresh which executes the call to get amount of messages read but it not updating the the counter, if i put a break point on the GetCounter method i see it is updating the counter with the right amount but not changing in on the badge.

Hope that makes sense.

If anyone can help i will be very grateful.

Master Tab Page:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Message" Icon="email.png"  plugin:TabBadge.BadgeText="{Binding counter}" 
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeColor="Red"
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionTopRight"
             plugin:TabBadge.BadgeTextColor="Green">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:MessagePage  BindingContext="{Binding messages}" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>



public partial class MasterTabPage : TabbedPage
{
    Master_PageViewModel vm;
    public MasterTabPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = vm = new Master_PageViewModel(Navigation);
    }
}
```

Master Tab Page ViewModel:

```
 public class Master_PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    INavigation Navigation;
    private int _counter;
    public int counter
    {
        get => _counter;
        set
        {
            _counter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(counter));

        }
    }
    public MessagePageViewModel messages { get; set; }
    public Master_PageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        Navigation = navigation;
        messages = new MessagePageViewModel(Navigation);
        Init();
        counter = 0;
    }
    public async void Init()
    {
        await GetCounter();
    }
    public async Task GetCounter()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                List<MessageModel> msg = new List<MessageModel>();

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:53665/api/GetMessagesCount/Id=" + 2 + "/" ))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            var textresponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MessageModel>>(textresponse);
                            foreach (var i in json)
                            {
                                msg.Add(new MessageModel
                                {
                                    msgCounter = i.msgCounter,
                                });
                            }
                            counter = msg[0].msgCounter;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Message Tab ViewModel:

```
public class MessagePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public ICommand MessageDetailsCommand { get; set; }
    INavigation Navigation;

    private ObservableCollection<MessageModel> _messagesList;
    public ObservableCollection<MessageModel> MessagesList
    {
        get { return _messagesList; }
        set
        {
            if (_messagesList != value)
            {
                _messagesList = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand ReloadCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                await GetMessages();
                Master_PageViewModel vm = new Master_PageViewModel(Navigation,multiMediaPickerService);
                await vm.GetCounter();
            });
        }
    }

    bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;

        }
    }
    public MessagePageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {


        ReloadCommand = new Command(async () => await ReloadPage());

        Navigation = navigation;
        MessageDetailsCommand = new Command(async (object obj) => await MessageDetails(obj));
        Initialize();

    }

    private async void Initialize()
    {

        await GetMessages();

    }

    private async Task ReloadPage()
    {
        await GetMessages();
    }


    public async Task GetMessages()
    {
        List<MessageModel> msg = new List<MessageModel>
           .........
        MessagesList = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>(msg);

    }

    private async Task MessageDetails(object obj)
    {
        var item = (obj as MessageModel);

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MessageDetailsPage(....));
    }

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you created a new instance of `Master_PageViewModel` in your `RefreshCommand`. It is not the parent tabbed page's binding context so the tab's badge won't be updated even though the `GetCounter` has been triggered.

You have to pass the parent tabbed view model to your `MessagePageViewModel` like:

```
public Master_PageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
{
    Navigation = navigation;
    messages = new MessagePageViewModel(Navigation, this);
    Init();
    counter = 0;
}
```

And change your message page view model's constructor:

```
Master_PageViewModel parentViewModel
public MessagePageViewModel(INavigation navigation, Master_PageViewModel viewModel)
{
    ReloadCommand = new Command(async () => await ReloadPage());

    Navigation = navigation;
    parentViewModel = viewModel;

    // ...
}
```

At last, trigger the method in your refresh command:

```
public ICommand RefreshCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            await GetMessages();
            await parentViewModel.GetCounter();
        });
    }
}
```

Moreover, I noticed that your `MessagePageViewModel` used the parent tabbed view model's navigation. I don't think this is a good approach as it has its own NavigationPage so that it should utilize its own navigation instead of the parent's.

Comment: Thank you very much Land Lu, appreciate you taking time out to help me with my problem.

Comment: @BryteNyte It's my pleasure.